# Error Installing Xcode 3.2.5 along with iOS SDk 4.2

Tags: macos, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-4.2

[image]Hi,

I am upgrading Xcode to 3.2.5 from 3.2.4 along with iOS SDK 4.2.

I keep getting following error message at the end of the installation:

"installation failed contact software manufacture".

Please check attached screenshot for more details.

Can you please suggest what needs to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Any more information that you can provide us about your particular configuration? What version of OS X are you running? Do you have a previous version of Xcode and/or the iOS SDK installed? etc.

Comment: We are running on Mac OSX 10.6.5 and we have iOS SDK 4.1

Answer (score 4):

roll your date back to 1/1/2012. Just had the same issue and that allowed it to finish!

Comment: Do you realize you are responding to a question asked in December of 2010? "Rolling back" ones date to 1/1/2012 would seem to be an invalid suggestion in light of that, don't you think?

Comment: It's not an invalid suggestion. Regardless of what the underlying issue is, or what would have worked in December 2010, this works *now*.

Answer (score 0):

Check the

> /var/log/install.log

file for any error it might log.

Comment: Hi Ismail, Thanks fo your reply but the problem is that I am not able to find this path. So can you please give the whole path where in I can get this? I am a newbie. Thanks for your input once again :)

Comment: Open Terminal.app and you can just use the command `open /var/log/install.log` and check the last messages.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Console.app (found in `/Applications/Utilities` folder) and check the output while XCode is installing. You may find some answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Expect it might be a permissions problem or related to a network lookup which fails.

Here are the detailed error messages I get from Console:

> The domain/default pair of (com.apple.iPhoneSDKInstaller, showAdvancedInstaller) does not exist

---

*Additional Installer logs:*

> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    Installer[4979] : the delegate  was sent -splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: and left the subview frames in an inconsistent state:
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    [0x0-0x194194].com.apple.installer  2012-05-22 10:19:11.627 Installer[4979:903] : the delegate  was sent -splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: and left the subview frames in an inconsistent state:
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    Installer[4979] Split view bounds: {{0, 0}, {402, 104}}
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    [0x0-0x194194].com.apple.installer  2012-05-22 10:19:11.629 Installer[4979:903] Split view bounds: {{0, 0}, {402, 104}}
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    Installer[4979]     Subview frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 32}}
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    [0x0-0x194194].com.apple.installer  2012-05-22 10:19:11.629 Installer[4979:903]     Subview frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 32}}
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    Installer[4979]     Subview frame: {{0, 0}, {402, 104}}
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    [0x0-0x194194].com.apple.installer  2012-05-22 10:19:11.629 Installer[4979:903]     Subview frame: {{0, 0}, {402, 104}}
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    Installer[4979] The outer edges of the subview frames are supposed to line up with the split view's bounds' edges. NSSplitView is working around the problem, perhaps at the cost of more redrawing. (This message is only logged once per NSSplitView.)
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:11 AM    [0x0-0x194194].com.apple.installer  2012-05-22 10:19:11.630 Installer[4979:903] The outer edges of the subview frames are supposed to line up with the split view's bounds' edges. NSSplitView is working around the problem, perhaps at the cost of more redrawing. (This message is only logged once per NSSplitView.)
>
> 2012/22/05 10:19:38 AM    Installer[4979] The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.