# Getting "Unknown iOS Detected" everytime in Xcode Organizer when I connect my device iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

[image]

I get the same screen everytime I connect my device to the Mac.

This thing started happening after I installed iOS 4.2.1 on my iPhone.

It takes several minutes each time to recognize the device when I connect it to Mac.

What can be a permanent fix?

**EDIT:**

My iOS SDK version is 4.2.1 and My Xcode version is is 3.2.5.

Comment: Have you tried, you know, clicking on that **Collect** button? Also please tag your question correctly, are you using SDK 3 or 4?

Comment: Sorry BoltClock but I didnt find a tag for SDK 4.2.1. If you find the tags wrong then it would be nice if you can please edit them.Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: OK but did you follow my instruction and click **Collect** and see what happens?

Comment: I tried that but then everytime I restart Mac and try to connect my device it asks for collect again. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the developer tools and Xcode and then reinstalled it again.

Then collected the symbols for the first time. Then it worked properly from second time onwards.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What maximum iOS version supports your xCode? You should update it to support the latest iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

As pictured in your screenshot, your device looks to be on 4.2.1. What version of Xcode are you using? You should be using the latest 3.2.5 with iOS 4.2.1 SDK.

If you are not on Xcode 3.2.5, then upgrade to that.

Comment: My current Xcode version is 3.2.5 but when we tried installing this Xcode then it was giving installation errors same as to the below Stackoverflow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530180/error-installing-xcode-3-2-5-along-with-ios-sdk-4-2